# Prevent sign from printing in printf C C++

Tags: c++, c, printf

By Default negative number signs are printed and by adding + flag one can print the plus sign if required.
I am looking to print a number without its sign.
I believe there is a flag for that but that doesn't seem to work.

```
printf("'%d'", 10); -->    '10'
printf("'%d'",-10); -->    '-10'
printf("'%+d'",10); -->    '+10'
```

It would be great if some can suggest how to print x for the inputs x and -x,(x>0).
*PS*: I don't like to operate on numbers, I am looking for a software feature.

Comment: Use `"%d"` and [`abs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs)?

Comment: `abs()` is a software (library) feature. `printf` formatting don't have syntax to omit the sign. Printing `-10` with `%u` will not be "10".

Comment: I wanted to do it without using abs.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Not sure why you object to `abs()` - but if not using that is imperative, use the ternary `(p<0?-p:p)` as an equivalent.

Comment: @user3121023, done. I still think using abs is better - unless this is done in compatibility mode in an old compiler without full (read STL/template) C++ support.

Comment: `abs(INT_MIN)` will likely fail OP's goal.

Comment: Maybe `char buf[50]; printf("%s", (sprintf(buf, "%+d", x), &buf[1]));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no flag in printf to do what you want, you can however use the abs() function, like this

```
printf("%d",abs(i));
```

where `i` is your variable.

This is for integers. You could also do binary operations on the number to shift it to its positive representation, but `abs()` already does that for you, so that would be superficial.

Take note that doing `abs(i)` does not modify `i` in any way, so its safe to use on your variables without copying them first.

Comment: I wasn't worried about modifying  the number instead I was looking for a feature that printf doesn't have(need). Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: This will have UB if `i==INT_MIN` and `int` represents negative numbers in two's complement (as is almost on all CPUs).

Answer (score 7):

> I am looking to print a number without its sign.

Nobody would want that as leaving the sign from a *negative* number makes it a **different** number.

> PS: I don't like to operate on numbers

Well, then do what you don't like ... `abs()` is the function you're looking for and expresses exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`printf("%d",abs(number));`

where number is the number you want to print.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you object to `abs()` - but if not using that is imperative, use the ternary `(p<0?-p:p)` as an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you could get away with simple character replacement. First print with sign, and then replace with another character:

```
char buf[99];
snprintf(buf, 99, "%+d'", 10); // +10'
buf[0] = '\'';  // '10'
printf("%s", buf);
```

But this is special case, and in general you should consider using `abs()` function.

Comment: Drop `buf[0] = '\'';` and use `printf("%s", &buf[1]);`.  Replacement not needed